# WPF application has old look (like win forms) in 2008 R2 server

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

After I uninstalled a third party product from VS 2013, any WPF app now looks like the old win forms. Before it was working fine and had the modern look of WPF. I went in Control Panel clicked the VS 2013 and clicked on Repair option. After awhile it completed successfully but made no difference. I want the modern look back.

UPDATE:

Ops! What I said above was not really the problem. What happened is that I ended up working on a remote 2008 R2 server (via RDP) and I found  [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740220/styles-not-loading-on-windows-server)

Comment: Did your .NET framework get uninstalled?  You might check the version.    Also, it might be theme-related.  Check your current theme.

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Comment: Are your Visual Effects set to 'Adjust for best performance' in the Performance Options for your PC?  On Windows 7 you can check this by right clicking your computer icon -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> and click the 'Settings' button under Performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link to the answer is in the question's update section.
The problem was not with VS 2013, but the remote server that needed to be setup properly.It looks awesome now.