# WPF datagrid different style depending on OS

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, datagrid, styles

I'm developing a WinForms app that uses some WPF user controls inside. One of them contains a WPF DataGrid, and I can see it in different styles depending on the OS in which it runs.

In Win7/Win8 I see it the same way (the context menu options have more height in Win 8 than in Win 7), but in Windows Server 2008 it seems to use a completely different ui style in the header row.

Windows 8:

[image: Running on Windows 8]

Windows server 2008:

[image]

After searching a little bit on the net, it seems to use different UI sources. I tried to manually put a white background with black foreground, but it loses the "gradient" style and I don't like the idea of creating a whole manual style.

Any help?

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////// **UPDATED** ////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I split the problem and created an exe with the most simple datagrid ever (one column and one context menu item). What a surprise when the colors are normal when I run the exe in a Windows server 2008 !!!

At the end I ended up founding what causes that ugly blue to be displayed. It's a common style that I use to force the datagrid to keep the "blue color" when the right click mouse button is pressed over a row. If I don't use this style, the row is greyed out when I right click over it.

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">        
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" />
        </Style.Resources>
 </Style>
```

Selected row (OK):

[image: Selected row]

Right-clicked row (bad):

[image: right-clicked row]

Right-clicked row with the style that causes bad colors in Windows server 2008 (black chars instead of white --> I would like to keep white chars):

[image]

Do you know the way to use a datagrid style to get what I need?

Comment: You might find some useful info on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740220/styles-not-loading-on-windows-server)

Comment: How about creating a style only for Windows Server and apply it after checking Environment.OSVersion?

Comment: @GordonTrue, the thread you tell me contains a guide to enable the windows user experience on windows server. It would be fine to fix the problem in my machine, but not worthy when I install the application in 500 client machines. I would like not to depend on the client side :(

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova mmm interesting, but I'm a bit confused with that property. For a win8 machine, the property values "Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0" and for the server2008 it values "Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1". I think it's not a good practise to rely on the string comparison.. how would you check that I'm running on win server??

Answer (score 1):

You can use numbers instead of strings to check the version:

```
Version win2008version = new Version(6, 1, 7601, 0);
if(Environment.OSVersion.Version == win2008version ) ...
```

In case you'll still need to determine the current version, to distinguish Win7 and Win2008 you can use product number (it's 1 for Win7 and 3 for  Win2008). You can get it calling [GetProductInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724358.aspx)

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
internal static extern bool GetProductInfo(
int osMajorVersion,
int osMinorVersion,
int spMajorVersion,
int spMinorVersion,
out int ProdunctNum); 

GetProductInfo(
Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major,
Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor,
0,
0,
out ProdunctNum);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that not only the header is disturbed, but also the context menu for example.

[image: Context menu colors on Windows Server 2008]

Instead of setting particular styles element by element, and applying them depending on the operating system, is it possible to tell WPF "try to use Aero styles for every component!"???

PS: I checked the version on different OS:

- Windows server 2008: **6.1.7601 SP 1**
- Windows 7: **6.1.7601 SP 1**
- Windows 8.1: 6.2.9200.0

So that on Win 2008 and Win 7 is the same!! :(